# How to improve Solr performance?

Tags: java, mysql, performance, solr, lucene

**How we are using Solr:** 
We are storing 7K documents with 3k attributes attached to one document in solr. Each attribute is indexed on solr to enable search/sort on these attribute. We are fetching data from solr based on search/filter criteria with 400+ attribute attached to one document. So when we try to search some text in solr with 1 attribute(by setting fl="projectId") it takes hardly 1 second to display result on solr console which is fine.

However if we try to fetch 100+ attribute for same search criteria (which will return string ~100*3* no of matched document(~50) out of 7K document with 4K attribute) it takes ~20 seconds. But we need to fetch 400+ attribute with matched document it takes long time ~90 seconds, earlier it was crashing due to outOfMemoryError  which we had fixed by increasing RAM size and JVM Heap size.

**Mysql Data sync with Solr:**
Currently we are using MySql DB as primary database and Solr Server as secondary database. We used to synch mysql data with Solr server on daily basis. We also update solr server whenever we update any attribute on Mysql DB.

**Using solr result data in application:**
Application dashboard will contain document with pre-configured columns(attributes) by user. User can apply search/filter criteria to populate required result on his dashboard. So our application try to fetch data with search/filter criteria from solr server by accessing it.

We have tried many things like increasing heap size, RAM size and no of CPU also but no luck. Data is increasing day by day which is causing lot of issues.
It is working for small no of projects or small no of attribute but whenever we try to fetch more attribute then it takes too much time, sometime it crashed.

I am not sure whether we are using indexes properly?

Can anyone suggest better/alternate approach?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How much data are we actually talking about that's attached to each document? If each document is a MB in size, you'll have to transfer large amounts of data when retrieving a list of documents.

Comment: each document contains ~1MB

Comment: how many documents are you returning? have you evaluated keeping a serialized version of the document in a cache and returning that, instead of getting the actual data from either Solr or MySQL?

Comment: @MatsLindh currently we are returning actual search result from solr. We have 2950 dynamic fields out of 3K and indexing through java code by committing SolrInputDocumentList in batches with no category defined all documents are on same level. 

I am thinking to add organization id as category and put relevant documents under the category.
Will it help improving my search performance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of getting 400 fields back for each document, you can get back just the "id" of each document and then get these documents from MySQL which is your permanent storage.

So for the example if you are getting back 25 document ids per search , in your application you can get the 25 docs from MySQL (may be do a parallel call)

In my experience returning more number of fields increases qTime a lot.

Comment: Yes I was thinking for the same, again it will take significant time to fetch data from mysql as well

Comment: @ManojP Solr is quick to find a data matching your conditions. Once you know every id matching your condition, MySql will answer immediatly since your only condition is on an indexed column (i.e the id). Then, fetching data from DB will be faster thanks to all the premade functions that are optimized. Parsing a Solr response will take much more time, since you will need to use an XML parser or whatever, which is much slower.

Comment: @ManojP the issue here is that you are returning too much data from solr. Applying filters / facets are not going to help. In your question you have mentioned that if you keep &fl=projectid it takes less than 1 second. If you think MySQL will also take significant time then the next best option for you is to look into a cache database like Memcached. When you are inserting data into MySQL/solr , insert that same data into memcached also. After getting projectids from solr , get the documents from memcached.

Comment: Thanks for your time and info, We have fixed this problem by adding MongoDB to populate data ( after getting id from solr).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use facet search - multiple searches that reduce the number of candidates on each successive search.

The other way is to use filters extensively.

If you can turn some of the query into filters (fq) that would probably increase performance on a good factor.

Comment: ok,  I will try to add my search/filter criteria into fq, I am not sure about facet search?